# Tensorflow CPU Version installation error (DLL load fail) Win7, Python 3.5.0

Tags: windows, tensorflow, installation, python-3.5

Been struggling on this on for 3 days. I already have tensorflow working on 3 other mahcines but need to install this on a high performance CPU going forward.
 Get following DLL Import error while trying to install tensorflow using pip.

Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU
System Type: 64-bit
Based on other solutions i have already tried

Have followed all instructions on the Tensorflow installation page

- have installed the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update
- Tried with Conda Package after installing multiple Anaconda versions
- Tried some alternate [whl][1] as I could not find my CPU in the AVX2
  CPU List
- Tried multiple individual versions (Python 3.5, 3.6, tensorflow
  1.12.0, 1.9.0, 1.6.0 etc) (i.e. without anaconda)

pywrap_tensorflow_internal import

ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

============================
(venv)

```
c:\software\Python35\venv\Lib\site-packages>echo %Path%

c:\software\Python35\venv\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\
System32\Wbem;C:\software\Python35;C:\software\Python35\venv\Lib\site-packages;
C:\software\Python35\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include\tensorflow;C:\software\curl


(venv) c:\software\Python35>pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.12.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\software\python35\venv\lib\site-packages
Requires: termcolor, grpcio, keras-preprocessing, wheel, absl-py, six, numpy, ke
ras-applications, astor, tensorboard, protobuf, gast
Required-by:

(venv) c:\software\Python35>cd c:\software\python35\venv\lib\site-packag
es

(venv) c:\software\Python35\venv\Lib\site-packages>python
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\software\Python35\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap
_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\software\Python35\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap
_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\software\Python35\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap
_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, descript
ion)
  File "c:\software\Python35\venv\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "c:\software\Python35\venv\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\software\Python35\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py",
 line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-im
port
  File "c:\software\Python35\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init
__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "c:\software\Python35\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap
_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\software\Python35\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap
_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\software\Python35\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap
_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\software\Python35\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap
_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, descript
ion)
  File "c:\software\Python35\venv\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "c:\software\Python35\venv\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried Python 3.6.0 install and Tensorflow 1.5.0. Got "google.protobuf.pyext import _message" error. So as per [this](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/5046) I upgraded to 3.6.1. I am able to Import tensorflow now! So looks like i have to be with tensorflow 1.5.0 version